# Etymology of "en train de"

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, indications-de-temps

Do you know the etymology of "en train de"? What does "train" mean and where it comes from?

Comment: Looks like it comes from the 15-th century, with complexities along the way: http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-en-train-de.php.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is a summary of what can be found in the *[Dictionnaire culturel en langue française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence:Dictionnaire_culturel_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)*.

**Train** comes from Old French *traginare*, that comes from Latin *trahere*. At first it meant a procession, a retinue, and English borrowed it in the 14th c. with exactly the same meaning, [see Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=train). 
In French it later evolved to mean the movement, the pace of a beast or a person and, preceded by *en*, in the 15th c. it was used for something on the move and *en train de* meaning "ready to". Since the 18th c. ***en train de*** is used to express the durative aspect of the verb which used to be expressed by the gerund (and still is in English)<sup>*</sup>.

---

Le nom **train** vient du latin populaire *traginare*, lui-même issu du latin *trahere* (tirer).

*Train* a d'abord (11<sup>e</sup> s.) désigné un ensemble de choses, un convoi, une file de choses voyageant ensemble (bêtes, hommes...).
Il a été employé au sens figuré dès le 17<sup>e</sup> s pour une série de pensées (« un train de pensées » et au 20<sup>e</sup> s. pour des actes à caractère officiel (« un train de mesures »).
Par un autre développement l'accent est mis sur l'allure, le mouvement d'une bête ou d'une personne (« aller à un train de sénateur »). D'après certains emplois attestés dès le 15<sup>e</sup> s. avec la prépopsition *en*, il est entré dans la locution adverbiale, *en train*  « en action, en movement, en cours d'exécution »,  et dans la locution prépositionnelle ***en train de*** qui voulait dire « disposé à ». Depuis le 18<sup>e</sup> s. l'emploi moderne de ***en train de*** exprime l'aspect duratif d'une action, qui s'exprimait précédemment par le gérondif (et qui s'exprime toujours ainsi en anglais)<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* Qu'on peut encore trouver en poésie mais pas dans le langage de tous les jours.  This gerund can still be found in poetry but not in every usage. (Voir la chanson *Un jeune homme chantait*, Raymond Asso, 1937. « Sur la route, la grand'route, Un jeune homme va chantant. Sur la route, la grand'route, Une fille va rêvant »)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

oui, cela vient de traginare, traîner. Il y a tout une petite thèse sur cette expression [ici](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00497581/document). Train désignait ce qui suit, mais aussi le mouvement.

L'expression a pris forme au XVIe : être en action, c'était alors suivi d'un nom commun (être en train de joie (ce qui voulait dire qu'on sentait l'humeur joyeuse plus que possible)). Cela s'est ensuite associé à de l'infinitif, et là, même chose: être en humeur de (donc être en train de manger, c'était avoir l'appétit qui nous travaille).

Ce n'est qu'au XIXème qu'on l'a utilisé pour exprimer ce qu'on est en train de faire (donc être en train de manger, c'est manger...).